# What does too broad mean in this context, and why was my question put on hold for this reason?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question of mine got closed with an explanation that does not seem to fit:

**[Does there Exist for LINQ any sort of indexing akin to FoxPro's Rushmore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048307/does-there-exist-for-linq-any-sort-of-indexing-akin-to-foxpros-rushmore)**

It was put on hold for being too broad. It was a very specific question, and it got a very specific answer, directly from a Microsoft representative, and that wouldn't have happened if it were not a decent question.

> Question: Is there an indexing technology like Rushmore for LINQ-to-Objects?
>   Answer: No

Can I get an explanation of what is "broad" about that, so I can keep that in mind in the future?

Comment: A question getting an answer (from a Microsoft rep, or not) does not automatically mean it's a good question.  It just means someone saw it and decided to answer it.  Correlation is not causation.

Comment: _downvotes seem to be like a slap in the face_ Even if your question is not broad, it is definetly off-topic. Asking for an off-site resource is not on-topic. _I wanted to know if there is any optimization technology for LINQ._ I recommend visiting the [tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the OP wanted to know, _is any optimization technology for LINQ.?_ They are asking us to find a technology for them and if someone knows it already then that's lucky.

Comment: @weegee reading the question the OP wanted to know if Linq used an optimization algorithm they were familiar with. Kinda like "searching for JavaScript's equivalent of Perl's "use"." (hint: an experienced person might ask instead "how do I import modules in JavaScript?") No one's asking for an off-site resource; they don't have the terminology to know what to call the thing they want to know exists in the language.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Exactly And that's what makes it off-topic. _they don't have the terminology to know what to call the thing they want to know exists in the language_  So they ask a question on SO. Like _"Is there a thing in java just like ruby had?"_ Hence they are asking us to find that thing. Off-site resource

Comment: A direct quote from the question: _"I want to know for LINQ-to-Objects, if there is something similar to Rushmore or the index-related performance optimizations in SQL Server?"_ To me, that looks like the OP is asking _"What function do I use to get the same effect as <X>"_. Imo, it's borderline, but I'd say it's too broad.

Comment: Your question was OK but on SO any question can be closed for no good reason. Those who voted there, likely didn't even know what Rushmore is at all. Maybe they voted to close because you acted to early to accept a reply as an answer.

Comment: @CetinBasoz It's also possible that it was raining at the time. What's the point? Close voting (and reopening, except when done by a mod) requires 3 votes. If it's truely worth staying open surely 3 people can come to that conclusion and reopen it.

Comment: You should be able to comment on your own questions regardless of reputation, I'm confused as to why you seemingly can't. FWIW: a) putting comments in questions/answers is frowned upon, especially if it *is* skirting rep restrictions; b) calling out specific users on Meta is frowned upon; c) rolling back other people's edits is probably going to end in a moderator locking the question; d) I don't see anywhere in that linked post where that user says they know what Rushmore is, unless they deleted their comment.

Comment: It really does strike me as too broad, primarily because we don't know what's really going on and therefore what the real solution to your actual problems is. The answer given by the MS guy (assuming he isn't lying) can be catastrophic if, for example, you're querying against a sql server database with 1m records. Calling ToDictionary on the context will rehydrate all your records. No Bueno. Knowing what you're attempting to do would go a long way to getting you actual answers to your practical question. That's the goal of the website.

Comment: Your latest edit to this question is being reverted because speculation about personal motivations is superfluous, and making this discussion personal achieves nothing.

Comment: Please don’t edit personal attacks into your question, regardless of how warranted you feel they are. I’d like to keep this question open as it’s a good question, but when you edit personal attacks into it we are either forced to edit them out or close the question.

Comment: @KevinB, rain doesn't have anything to do with the question. If you don't understand the question you shouldn't vote for close in the first place.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you don’t know what you don’t know.

Comment: This was a good question, and this was an awful experience for a senior developer just trying to get back into development and trying to improve his reputation so that he can merely comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, @MicroservicesOnDDD, what you think is a good question isn't what the community thinks is a good question.  If you want to be able to comment, I would suggest making some good edits to existing posts, or spend some time observing the site, and then asking questions based on what you've learnt by those observations.

Answer (score -23, accepted):

The question wasn't too broad: Does `<technology>` use `<optimization>`? Is what it boils down to. It either does or it doesn't.  No one would be tempted to turn their answer into a book.

The question isn't based on 'opinion'.

The question is answerable, especially since [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) is available.

The question wasn't asking for an off-site resource. You weren't asking someone to provide you with a library, website, or book that does "X", you were asking if "X" exists in technology "Y", that we all happen to use because we're programmers.

The hangup people (probably) had with the question was that it wasn't based on an actual problem you face, rather it is a question you're asking because you're curious.

You know, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548221/does-c20-mandate-source-code-being-stored-in-files), that was inhabiting the Hot Network Questions list for most of this morning.

Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on your point of view) there is no close reason for "This is a curiousity I have but I haven't actually tried to do in the wild", and so sometimes questions get closed for reasons that don't make sense.  This is one of those unwritten 'rules' of Stack Overflow, that may or may not get enforced depending on how interesting the question is.

Comment: So we now dig up any ancient, long forgotten optimization trick and ask if it is available in a modern stack. Only the OP and myself probably know what rushmore was and did for foxpro performance. If there are any future visitors that are going to search for that technology I hope they find it before they go extinct ;)

Comment: @rene you can say " the question should be closed", but you'd be hard pressed to close it with a valid reason from our close list without resorting to mental gynmastics.

Comment: I didn't had to use much mental gymnastics. Asking for index optimaztion in Linq-to-objects is too broad. Despite all that, I still like the edit you gave to that question, so kudos for that.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Lewis it's not a software library. LINQ is a built-in for C#; he's asking if they used a certain technique to make their indexing fast. He's not asking for a library.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Then the summation of the question is incorrect: _"Is there an indexing technology like Rushmore"..._ That sounds to me like asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @Lewis That's where I think the users went wrong. If you're familiar with memoization; it'd be akin to asking if Redis uses memoization in order to speed up lookups.  It's not a library they're looking for, they're asking whether a particular pattern was used in the construction of LINQ.

Comment: I'm not unfortunately, so I can accept your word on that. I'd recommend to the OP in that scenario to remove the text asking for software similar to Rushmore (still in place in the original question) and focus on the _"index-related performance optimizations"_. Or at least, just reconsider the wording of the question.

Comment: I feel like this question misses the forest for the trees.  User comes in with an outdated concept from over a decade ago, and wants to know if a modern language provides the same functionality, without actually determining if that concept is even still relevant in today's environments.  If it's not too broad...I dunno.  It's like asking if we can still store data on cassette tapes because you last coded on a Trash-80.

Comment: @fbueckert many of the best practices we use for data are from the 70s. Not so sure we can call a decade ago “outdated”

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Care to remove the lock on the question? It seems just about everyone except you agrees that this should be closed.

Comment: @jhpratt I didn’t say it shouldn’t be closed, I said that none of the reasons given fit.

Comment: @jhpratt, I don't agree it should be closed either.

Answer (score 25):

I'm one of the close voters of that SO question.

Your question doesn't present a practical programming problem. At best it tries to envision and invite members to offer an equivalent for a proprietary technology that was more geared to database files then to in memory collections.

That simply is either too broad or asking for an off-site resource.

It could have been useful if the question included a specific use case where your current approach doesn't meet your requirements. The lack of such practical use case makes the question in that state it was in when under review, too broad.

The answer you accepted on that question might have helped you but it does nothing for what you actually asked. Either the context you provided doesn't matter or you needed to solve a different problem you didn't mention in your question.

Do know there exists a vibrant community on Stack Exchange called [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where you can either find or ask background stories on "long" forgotten technologies. Maybe the question, with a bit of retro-fitting, could fly there, so you have extra information you could have used for the development task you faced and wanted to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OP's marking one answer as a reply, doesn't make the question eligible for being closed. I believe, those who voted for close, including you didn't know and understand what the question was about at all.

Comment: @CetinBasoz noted, thanks for the kind feedback, appreciated.

Comment: The file vs memory thing is a bit of a red herring here, IMHO. I've seen folks write code to query in-memory data more slowly than a well-indexed file DB could produce the same results; I'm confident that sort of dubious feat is achievable with LINQ as well. Indexing - and the judicious use of indexes to avoid having to repeatedly iterate through a large set of data - is still a useful skill. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641058/linq-to-objects-and-improved-perf-with-an-index

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough. That still wasn't asked in the question in question.